# MySQL UTF8 Data Not Being Displayed Properly

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, latin1

I want all the data in MySQL to be UTF8 encoded.  I've set all the character sets and collations to be UTF8 for the database, tables and columns.  Before anything is written to the database, I use mb_detect_encoding in PHP to check if it is UTF8.  Thus, I believe all the data is UTF8 encoded.

However, here is the problem: take this word Ríkarðsdóttir, it shows up correctly when queried from the database and displayed through PHP on a UTF8 encoded webpage.  If I query this same record through phpMyAdmin, I get RÃ­karÃ°sdÃ³ttir.  The same is true if I use the MySQL command line.

```
Running SHOW VARIABLES returns to me:
character_set_client    utf8,
character_set_connection    utf8,
character_set_database  utf8,
character_set_filesystem    binary,
character_set_results   utf8,
character_set_server    latin1,
character_set_system    utf8
```

Only the server is latin1, and I am on a shared hosting site and don't believe I can change that.  Could that be the problem?

Here is what I do not understand: why does my UTF8 webpage correctly display Ríkarðsdóttir, but a UTF8 encoded phpMyAdmin webpage display it as RÃ­karÃ°sdÃ³ttir?  Is the data not truly UTF8 encoded or does the database not believe it is?  What needs to be done to correct this?

Answer (score 3):

Try running this query right after you connect:

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Your database needs to store the data as UTF8, and your web page header should also have a UTF8 declaration, but your connection to the database also needs to use UTF8. You can run that on the command line and/or through PHPMyAdmin. All communication after that "query" will then be UTF8 encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; however, it did not fix the problem. I tried the SET NAMES 'utf8' query through the mysql shell and added it to phpMyAdmin, but it did not affect the display of the data in either case.

Per the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html, A SET NAMES 'x' statement is equivalent to these three statements:
SET character_set_client = x; SET character_set_results = x; SET character_set_connection = x

Per a SHOW VARIABLES query they are all set to UTF8. Somehow mysql seems to be storing UTF8 data in some other encoding, latin1 presumably.

Comment: You can try running ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 to make sure the data is stored in UTF8.